# Nested dictionary subtraction

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

i have two nested dictionaries

```
x =  {
    "P1": {
        "output": {
            "error": 0,
            "error rate": 20
        },
        "input": {
            "sampling rate": 100,
            "xyz": 200
        }
    },
    "P2": {
        "output": {
            "error": 0,
            "error rate": 20
        },
        "input": {
            "sampling rate": 100,
            "xyz": 200
        }
    }}

y =  {
    "P1": {
        "output": {
            "error": 10,
            "error rate": 10
        },
        "input": {
            "sampling rate": 10,
            "xyz": 20
        }
    },
    "P2": {
        "output": {
            "error": 10,
            "error rate": 30
        },
        "input": {
            "sampling rate": 100,
            "xyz": 200
        }
    }}
```

I am trying to do the following to get the difference between two nested dictionary

difference : z = x - y

```
output: z =  {
    "P1": {
        "output": {
            "error": -10,
            "error rate": 10
        }
        "input": {
            "sampling rate": 90,
            "xyz": 180
        }
    },
    "P2": {
        "output": {
            "error": -10,
            "error rate": -10
        }
        "input": {
            "sampling rate": 0,
            "xyz": 0
        }
    }}
```

i used some form of below code

```
for key, x in y.items():
    newdct = {}
    for ikey, ival in x.items():
        for key, value in ival.iteritems():
            print key, value
            newdct[ikey] = value - y.get(key, 0)
    res[key] = newdct
```

This is not giving me the expected result. 
Is there an easier elegant and simple method of subtracting two nested dictionaries, consider that the keys are known and fixed.

Comment: Why should z.P1.output.error be 0 when x.P1.output.error=0 and y.p1.output.error=10?  Shouldn't you be concerned w/ correctness before elegance or simplicity?

Comment: it should be -10, basically the difference

Comment: or will it be easier to manipulate if i have a list in the dictionary ,  {
    "P1": {
        "output": [
            "error": 0,
            "error rate": 20
        ],
        "input": [
            "sampling rate": 100,
            "xyz": 200
        ]
}

Comment: Illegal code is easier to manipulate in that you can't do anything with it.

Comment: This is easy to do with pandas: https://pastebin.com/raw/zWRLfdgB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works even if not all numeric values are at the same level (but they do have to match between x & y):

```
def rec_diff( d1, d2 ):
    diff = dict()
    for k,v1 in d1.items():
        if isinstance( v1,dict ):
            diff[k] = rec_diff( v1, d2[k] )
        else:
            diff[k] = v1 - d2[k]
    return diff
z = rec_diff( x, y )
```

Answer (score 1):

How about recursion?

```
def find_diffs(d1, d2):
    if isinstance(d1, dict) and isinstance(d2, dict):
        return {k: find_diffs(d1.get(k, 0), d2.get(k, 0)) for k in d1 if k in d2}
    else:
        return d1- d2

find_diffs(x, y)
{'P1': {'input': {'sampling rate': '90', 'xyz': '180'},
  'output': {'error': '-10', 'error rate': '10'}},
 'P2': {'input': {'sampling rate': '0', 'xyz': '0'},
  'output': {'error': '-10', 'error rate': '-10'}}}
```

Comment: Why bother to check both `d1` & `d2` being `dict`s?  If only one is, the subtraction will raise an error.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
def process_dicts(d1, d2, result, proc):
    if (not isinstance(d1, dict)) or (not isinstance(d2, dict)) or (not isinstance(result, dict)) or (not callable(proc)):
        raise TypeError

    for key, value in d1.iteritems():
        if key not in d2:
            raise ValueError

        if isinstance(value, dict):
            result[key] = {}
            process_dicts(value, d2[key], result[key], proc)
        else:
            result[key] = proc(value, d2[key])
```

Usage:

```
res = {}
process_dicts(dict1, dict2, res, lambda a, b: a - b)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a one liner?

```
z={a:{b:{c:x[a][b][c]-y[a][b][c] for c in x[a][b].keys()} for b in x[a].keys()} for a in x.keys()}
```